# Saving a file in a UWP web context

Tags: javascript, uwp, webcontext

I recently developed a universal application for Windows 10 with UWP web context (so JavaScript and HTML) and I would like to save a text file. It works well on a browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge,...) but not in the application.
Can someone help me? :)
Thank you in advance!

Here is the code responsible for saving the text file.

```
function saveTextAsFile(fileName) {
var source = input.value.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");
var fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([source], {type:"text/plain"}));
var downloadLink = createDownloadLink(fileUrl, fileName);

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [DownloadsFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.downloadsfolder) and how to save a file there.

Comment: I can't use C# method  It's the problem.

Comment: That's not a C# method - it's a WinRT method. You can call WinRT APIs from JavaScript. See [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess/js) for example

Answer (score 1):

To download a file using a Progressive Web App as a Universal Windows Platform you can use the `Windows` global object with the `FileSavePicker`. Note that you can check to see if it exists using `if (window['Windows'] != null) { ... }`

```
// Create the picker object and set options
var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
savePicker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.documentsLibrary;
// Dropdown of file types the user can save the file as
savePicker.fileTypeChoices.insert("Plain Text", [".txt"]);
// Default file name if the user does not type one in or select a file to replace
savePicker.suggestedFileName = "New Document";

savePicker.pickSaveFileAsync().then(function (file) {
    if (file) {
        // Prevent updates to the remote version of the file until we finish making changes and call CompleteUpdatesAsync.
        Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.deferUpdates(file);
        // write to file
        Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, fileContents).done(function () {
            // Let Windows know that we're finished changing the file so the other app can update the remote version of the file.
            // Completing updates may require Windows to ask for user input.
            Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.completeUpdatesAsync(file).done(function (updateStatus) {
                if (updateStatus === Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus.complete) {
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + file.name + " was saved.", "sample", "status");
                } else {
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + file.name + " couldn't be saved.", "sample", "status");
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Operation cancelled.", "sample", "status");
    }
});
```

This assumes you are downloading a text file. To download a `Uint8Array` use the `WriteBytesAsync` function on `FileIO` instead. Note that many of the functions on `FileIO` are available in JavaScript even though they are not [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileio.writebytesasync) for JavaScript.

Check out the [FileSavePicker Class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker#code-try-2) for more information.